# How to test dkms / simulate a kernel update?

Tags: drivers, kernel, dkms

My presently used kernel does not yet support my Ethernet chip.
Therefore I installed dkms, added my driver as described in [Realtek-r8125 wiki, auto-translated to English](https://wiki-ubuntuusers-de.translate.goog/Howto/Realtek-r8125/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de) ([original in German](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Howto/Realtek-r8125/)) and want to check whether everything works fine.

I do not want to wait until the next kernel update happens to come. Therefore my question is:

**How can I test that everything works fine / simulate a kernel update?**

For the sake of completeness, please find in the following some technical details of my environment:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.4.0-109-generic (buildd@ubuntu) (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)) #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 09:10:54 UTC 2022
```

Comment: You can manually install some kernel, e.g. a mainline and see if the module builds OK. Use the same 5.4.x kernel. But a better idea would be to install a HWE kernel form the official repos. It will install the 5.13 kernel that doesn't require this module. BTW Mint is off-topic.

Comment: Just reinstall your current kernel?